# Order photos so bad photos arent visible (or very difficult to)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope

I have a problem. In my app, in "Latest photos", "featured photos", I want to hide those BAD photos that users upload, so only the best photos are in the top part of the application.

Which is the best approach to do this?

I thought about putting a column `:order` into `:photos` table, and make a scope that lists the photos in that order. But that wouldn't be real because they wouldn't be the latest photos or the most visited.

Please help!

Thanks!

Comment: What makes a photo good or bad? I mean, which criteria are you using to determine this?

Comment: Its a personal criteria, Moderators will be filtering @OscarValdezEsquea

Comment: So they will be tagging pictures as "good" or "bad"?

Comment: Maybe a scale , from 0 to 10 or something @OscarValdezEsquea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments above, I would use a column named something like moderator_rating and a custom scope involving created_at and moderator_rating. The scope might filter out photos rated below a certain value or uploaded too long ago. From there, I would start with the simplest thing that can possibly work for what you're doing and tweak as needed based on experimentation. So probably order by created_at with a sensible cutoff of moderator_rating.

Comment: Beat me to it. Technically what i was thinking :) (y)

Comment: Thank you! Will try it this way!